# How to store LinkedIn API oauth secret key once approved?

Tags: php, api, oauth, linkedin-api

I need someones help with the LinkedIn API.

I'm currently setting requestToken, oath_verifier and oauth_access_token from the session once the I accept the connection. This all works fine but obviously when the session ends I have to approve the app again to see my data.

```
32. $linkedin->request_token    =   unserialize($_SESSION['requestToken']);
33. $linkedin->oauth_verifier   =   $_SESSION['oauth_verifier'];
34. $linkedin->access_token     =   unserialize($_SESSION['oauth_access_token']);
```

How would I manually set these once I have accepted the connection once, so I don't have to approve my app every time I use it? At the moment I am saving the following values in my db but when I use the code below I am getting syntax errors in my PHP?

How can I rewrite the code below so it works?

```
32. $linkedin->request_token    =   OAuthConsumer['key=1234-1234,secret=4321-4321'];
33. $linkedin->oauth_verifier   =   '1234';
34. $linkedin->access_token     =   OAuthConsumer['key=5678-5678,secret=8765-8765'];
```

Here is the error code:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/pjharrison/test/index.php on line 32
```

Thanks
Pete

Answer (score 0):

To store the OAuth tokens across sessions, you'd need to use a more permanent storage medium, such as your favorite flavour of database, like [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/).

You'd then need to map tokens to returning users, via user accounts. When user A logs in to your site, you would have their stored OAuth tokens and could make calls via the LinkedIn [REST API](https://developer.linkedin.com/rest) using the tokens.

Comment: Thanks for your response Paul. Sorry I missed this part out of the description above. I am already storing the values in the database but when I print them out like the second example above I get syntax errors in my PHP.

Comment: Where does `OAuthConsumer` come from?